# How to migrate a Microsoft Virtual PC VM to a physical Disk?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, microsoft-virtual-pc

Most information I see is about migrating physical machines to VMs. I'm looking to do the opposite: take a VM in Microsoft Virtual PC and migrate it to a physical computer.

Judging from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/9350/convert-a-windows-vm-to-physical-partition), it looks like there are a few gotchas when migrating a VMWare guest OS to a physical disk, but disk imaging software should do the trick. Are there any other, better, options available to Microsoft Virtual PC users?

Comment: Please clarify.  You have a Microsoft Virtual PC, and you want to use that with a physical computer?

Comment: @wizlog, that is correct. I've set up an OS on a Vm and want to migrate that to a physical computer. (I've edited my question for clarity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK... Once you have a VMW OS, you seem to know what to do, so I will get you to that point.

Try using [VMware vCenter Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) and download it for free [here](http://www.vmware.com/go/getconverter).  They say they can "Convert other virtual machine formats such as... Microsoft Virtual PC"

Comment: Looks like disk imaging is my best bet. Thanks.