# How to convert a VMWare virtual disk to a physical disk?

Tags: boot, vmware, centos, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a Windows VM to physical partition](https://superuser.com/questions/9350/convert-a-windows-vm-to-physical-partition)

I have a dual boot setup with Windows 7 and Ubuntu installed. I also have a VMWare image with CentOS and want to migrate this to my physical drive so I would have all 3 in the boot menu. The idea is that I have sensible data on my computer and I haven't found a reliable and tested method that would guarantee that it is safe.

How can I accomplish this? I have worked with VMWare before but never come across this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/q/9350/108226

Comment: @Indrek: Thanks, this is a preety solution but after making the image and putting on my computer how can I can add it to the windows boot menu still ponders me

Comment: @KA_lin - Your question makes no sense.  If you follow the directions to convert a Virtual Machine into a physical parition you should be able to boot to that parition.  The process of adding a new boot parition to the boot menu is WELL documented.